# draw graph manually

Tags: graphing-functions

We have to draw the the graph(not excat) of {2x}/{x} manually without using any software or application . Where x belongs to (1,2) .

Where {.} denotes fractional part function .

Can any body help me out in this . I am not getting any start .

I can plot that for any specific number but how to draw for infinite numbers .

Comment: On $[1,2[$, $\{x\}=x-1$. On $[1,1.5[$, $\{2x\}=2x-2$, and on $[1.5,2[$, $\{2x\}=2x-3$...

Comment: Thanks , I got it@NicolasFRANCOIS